# Mudar ícone de menu da ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbar

Quero mudar o ícone de menu da `ActionBar`, aqueles 3 pontos que tem como opção padrão "Settings".
Já tentei pelo *Style* criando um tema customizado e lá colocando o novo ícone mas não funcionou.

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/botaohome</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@drawable/actionbuttonwhite</item>
</style>
```

O `homeAsUpIndicator` funciona perfeitamente, porém não aconteceu o mesmo com o Action Button Style.
Alguma dica ?

Comment: VocÊ falar colocar icone no botão Settings que vem como padrão?

Comment: Isso, esse mesmo! Alguma ideia?

Comment: Você pode desativar a action bar e ativar uma Toolbar. Nela vc teria total controle, cor, ícones e etc.

Comment: Tem um outro tópico aqui sobre isso, veja <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733312/changing-overflow-icon-in-the-action-bar> Creio que esse vídeo também poderá ajudá-lo <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycpgcx_QB3Y>

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um menu dentro de um Item, ai no item você define um icon

```
<item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_opcoes"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/comecar">
        <menu>

             //aqui coloca os itens que você quer dentro no menu

        </menu>
    </item>
```

Comment: Não é o ícone do launcher que ele quer mudar, e sim aqueles três pontinhos que aparecem no lado direito da action bar que abrem opções de menu (_overflow icon_).

Comment: Ataa, espera ai que eu acho que jã fiz isso, vou olhar aqui e já te falo

Comment: olha ai se e isso mesmo

Comment: Seria assim se fosse um ícone customizado e não o ícone padrão do Android para a ação de overflow, que é mais complicado de mudar (justamente porque o Android tenta mantê-lo padrão). O que ele quer é isso aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506184/how-to-change-the-option-menu-icon-in-the-action-bar

Comment: É isso mesmo que o Piovezan falou. Mudar a cor deste ícone também me ajudaria bastante, se alguém souber.

Comment: Vou tentar esse link.